# using AWS java SDK in Scala

Tags: scala, aws-java-sdk

I'm modifying some parts of spark core which is written in Scala. Towards that, I want to call AWS Java API. As far as I know, it is possible to import java libraries in Scala code as there are already java library calls and import in Scala code like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ScheduledFuture, TimeUnit}
```

Here they are importing some built-in java libraries. But, I do want to import AWS Java SDK. In their official documentation, they say that to use the SDK we should add the dependency to the project `pom.xml` file to be able to build the project using `mv`:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.106</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm wondering whether this is enough or not? Can I now import AWS Java classes in spark Scala source code?

Comment: If you're using Maven instead of SBT, then yes. Have you tried?

Comment: Look for sample Maven Scala projects. There are plenty of sample projects in GH using `aws-java-sdk` in Scala, have you searched? Not really related to your question here, but FYI, There are also non-official Scala wrappers around `aws-java-sdk`, e.g. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-scala-sdk.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I now import AWS Java classes in spark Scala source code?

Yes